# Separate split for command output in vim

Tags: vim, split

When you type a command it will show the output until you press enter.

How can I make a vertical split to show have window at the bottom displaying command output?

Comment: So you basically want a seperate vertical split window that'll show the output of every command? Should it be closed with enter after it's done? Should it clean the output with enter after it's done? I have no idea how to do this, but more information is probably needed.

Comment: I would prefer it to always be open, it's mostly so I can view error output from clang. Whether it's cleared or not doesn't really matter to me, I guess I would like it to be cleared whenever I run make but if I know the command to clear it I can prepend it to my build mapping.

Comment: If you want error output from a compiler check out [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic), it'll point out errors in your code and present them to you in a quickfix window and/or in the command line when hovered over. It doesn't sound like a split window is what you actually want. Maybe you want to use tmux to have a split window with a shell?

Comment: See also `:help shell-window`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this command which does what I want:

`:make! | copen`

Here's my build mapping that I used modified to use the above:

```
nnoremap <F5> :wa<CR>:make! run \| copen<CR>
```

Comment: Jump the next/previous error via `:cnext`/`:cprevious`. I suggest taking a look at `:h quickfix` for more information.